# Open vbp files with Visual Studio 2010 professional

Tags: visual-basic

I want to open a vbp file with Visual Studio 2010.  I know that previous versions of Visual Studio have the Visual Basic Upgrade Wizard.  Does 2010 have this, and if so, how do I use it.